# Count sub directories that starts a specific character and specify length in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have a directory structure in Windows which looks like this:

```
\Root 
    \SUB-DIR1
        \A1
        \B1
        \AA1
    \SUB-DIR2
        \A2
        \C2
        \AA2
   \SUB-DIR3
        \A3
        \B3
        \AA3
```

I would like to count *directories* (not files) using a query such as *"starts with 'AA' and the the length of the subdirectory name is 3"*.

I've tried:

```
$f = get-childitem -Path C:\ROOT -recurse 
Write-Host $f.Count
```

...but I am not sure how to filter specific child items and get count of that.  Powershell or Cmd would be of great help.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you'd like the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the directory names with a regex. Pattern `^AA.$` will match strings that begin (`^`), got (`AA`), have one more a character (`.`) and the string ends (`$`). As the dot will match just about anything, dirs like AAA, AAB, AA! etc are included too. Like so,

```
# In addition, include only directories by checking PsIsContainer
gci Root -Recurse | ? { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.name -match "^AA.$" }
```

As how to get the count, either output the gci into an array and check its count member or pass the results to `Measure-Object` and select the count member.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, that's what I meant by the "output the gci into an array and check its count member" part.